# What does "pyenv virtualenvwrapper" do?

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper, pyenv

I am using pyenv with virtualenvwrapper.

For using virtualenvwrapper (without pyenv) I have in my .bash_profile ***source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh***

When using pyenv with virtualenvwrapper plugin what exactly does ***pyenv virtualenvwrapper*** do ?

What I see online is this is required to *setup a virtualenvwrapper into your shell*. Is it still required if I have sourced virtualenvwrapper.sh ?

To add some more details: as per 
https://alysivji.github.io/setting-up-pyenv-virtualenvwrapper.html

```
Anytime we install a new version of Python, we will need to install 
virtualenvwrapper. This is done with either the pyenv 
virtualenvwrapper or pyenv virtualenvwrapper_lazy
```

Is it required only once when a new version of python is installed in pyenv ?

Answer (score 0):

In short, from the pyenv-virtualenvwrapper [readme](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper):

> pyenv-virtualenvwrapper is a pyenv plugin which provides a pyenv virtualenvwrapper command to manage your virtualenvs with virtualenvwrapper.

There are three tools involved here:

1. [**`virtualenv`** or **`venv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) - Used for isolating python environments (collections of packages) by using 'virtual environments'. `virtualenv` has been more or less superseded by `venv`, but for the purpose of this answer, they are interchangeable.
2. [**`virtualenvwrapper`**](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) - A set of tools for automating some of the steps involved in using `virtualenv` or `venv`.
3. [**`pyenv-virtualenvwrapper`**](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper) is a plugin that allows `virtualenvwrapper` to work with `pyenv`
4. [**`pyenv`**](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) - a tool for managing multiple versions of python on the same computer system.

Another way to manage virtual environments when using `pyenv` is [`pyenv-virtualenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)